# why this.$t('hello') vue i18n not work at data property until i refresh page but when in use in normal template works

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

**i have placed image below of my components i need to translate title and content form the array in home component and bind props to info component as u said $t does not work with data  method how can i achieve with computed
pls help  **

[home component][1]
[info component][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKRXq.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWbt2.png

Answer (score 2):

`$t` is a computed property and is not accessible from within the `data` method. To work around, make `content` a `computed` property.

It looks like you're rendering the result of some query, so make that a prop that's passed into your component, then consume the prop in your computed property:

```html
<template>
<div>
  <span>{{infonew.id}}</span>
  <heading>{{infonew.title}}</heading>
  <section>{{content}}</section>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'InfoNews',
  props: ['infonew'],
  computed: {
    content () {
      return this.$t(this.infonew.content);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank's but how can  i want to bind it to a content like ```<InfoNews
            :id="infonew.id"
            :title="infonew.title"
            :content="infonew.content"
          />```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'll update my post.

Comment: **why when i pass as a prop array i can not see  the data properties being displayed by interpolation as you shown me displayed** as ``<InfoNews
            :infonews="infonews"
          />``

Comment: Because `infonews` is an array and the component is assuming an object. Because it's an array I assume you are displaying a list, so you'll want something like `<InfoNews v-for="item in infonews" :infonews="item" />`

Comment: i have send an image my code pls help am new to vue js